# Can JSON field not be a string?

Tags: java, json

As far as I know, all JSON field names are string values. However, I encountered a code snippet that does a string check on the "keys" of JSON to see if it's a string, and if not, it throws an exception. It goes something like:

```
if (!(key instanceof String)){
    throw new exception();}
```

Is this check necessary?

EDIT:

For example,

```
while (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME){
    String key = jp.getCurrentName();
}
```

This code snippet will only progress to JSON tokens that are strings, so I was wondering if a JSON could contain fieldnames that are not strings so that Jackson parser will simply skip those fieldnames.

Comment: It depends? I know in GSON, all keys must be strings

Comment: @Jeeter When you say "in GSON, all keys must be strings", do you mean "GSON parser assumes that keys are string, and will throw exception if it doesn't"? I am building one using Jackson Library, and it also seems to assume that the key will be String as `getCurrentName` will return a string, not an object, so I was wondering how to Jackson will handle non-String fieldnames, and if a valid JSON can even contain a non-string fieldname.

Comment: Can you show what parser you're using? Show us what `key` is, how it's declared, what created it.

Comment: This doesn't make very much sense. If the parser ends up with an object reference that isn't a String, that's the parser's fault.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am using Jackson Streaming API, and the JSON is not generated by Jackson. I will be scraping JSON files and inputting to Jackson for consumption

Comment: Yes, show us a relevant snippet of where `key` comes from.

Comment: There are different libraries for JSON and it solely depends on your logic if you need such a check. If you are storing your data in a JSON object to start with then you can use setString and setInt functions. If you are getting data from JSON then it is your model and you know if it is a string or not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry for not being clear. I updated my question. Not sure if that addresses it.

Comment: This (the example code) makes less sense, unfortunately. If the declared type of the variable `key` is `String`, the only thing the `instanceof` is doing here is checking if its value is `null`. You can only store `String` values in `String` variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JSON official website](http://json.org) (and by proxy, the [JSON Data Interchange Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)):

[image]

When creating an object, the key must be a `String`.

---

EDIT: As @SotiriosDelimanolis pointed out in the comments, this only applies to the format of the JSON file, not necessarily once parsed through a Java library.

> Jackson, for example, can deserialize keys into custom types - @SotiriosDelimanolis